# Angularjs: Why ng-repeat orderBy: re-sort incorrectly when data property change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use orderBy to sort my data in ng-repeat by is_important property & desc, like below:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in datas | orderBy:'-is_important'">{{data.id}}</li>

$scope.datas =  [{"id":"1","is_important":"0"},
                 {"id":"2","is_important":"0"},
                 {"id":"3","is_important":"0"},
                 {"id":"4","is_important":"1"},
                 {"id":"5","is_important":"0"},
                 {"id":"6","is_important":"0"}];
```

At the beginning, the order show on the screen is correct

```
4
1
2
3
5
6
```

But when I change the is_important property

```
$scope.datas[3].is_important = 0;
$scope.datas[5].is_important = 1;
```

the result displayed by ng-repeat :

```
1
2
3
5
6
4
```

isn't same as my expected answer:

```
6
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why?

this is my code:
http://jsbin.com/oMUSeHO/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in `change` method you set `is_important` to digit.

```
$scope.datas[3].is_important = 0;
$scope.datas[5].is_important = 1;
```

Change it as follows

```
$scope.datas[3].is_important = "0";
$scope.datas[5].is_important = "1";
```

Comment: I am sorting descending by date and was puzzled that changing date made items jump to the bottom. This answer made me realize that I am using date strings when the list is first created, and then using date objects when list data is changed. Thanks :-)